# Mime incorreto para arquivos XLS

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, mime-type

Eu estou fazendo uma migração de um determinado sistema escrito em ASP.NET (site) e em determinada parte desse sistema há um local onde se faz upload de uma arquivo `XLS`.

Existe uma checagem em relação ao mime type do arquivo para saber se o mesmo é de fato um arquivo XLS.

Isso funcionava perfeitamente no antigo servidor, porém depois da migração, tanto na minha máquina (Windows 7 Ultimate SP1), como no servidor de produção (Windows 2016 Datacenter) os mimes de arquivos XLS são reconhecidos como "application/octet-stream".

Só pra constar: Não tenho na minha máquina nem no servidor o Microsoft Office instalado (e acho que também seria um grande atraso depender disso só pra ter os mimes corretos). E também acho improvável que eu deva alterar o código para verificar a extensão, visto que isso não traz nenhum tipo de benefício quanto à segurança da aplicação.

Existe alguma forma de fazer esse mime ser reconhecido de fato?

O trecho do código é esse abaixo:

```
string Type = UP_Dados.PostedFile.ContentType;

string[] AllowedTypes = {
    "application/vnd.ms-excel", "application/ms-excel", "application/x-msexcel"
};

if (! System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(AllowedTypes, Type))
{
    Page.RegisterStartupScript(",", "<script>alert('O arquivo deve ser um XLS')</script>");

    return;
}
```

Comment: Qual é o valor que a variável  `Type` toma?

Answer (score 1):

O [**`HttpPostedFile.ContentType`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.contenttype(v=vs.110).aspx) não pega o *mime-type* do arquivo durante a execução, ele pega o *content-type* que **o navegador** informou no *payload* durante a requisição, ou seja que determinou este *content-type* que você vê foi o navegador, ou seja a detecção do conteúdo ocorre antes do upload e ocorre na máquina do usuário.

Isso digo logo que não é uma maneira tão confiável, pois **qualquer requisição HTTP pode ser manipulada**.

Por exemplo em uma requisição de upload de um arquivo valido que fiz, chamado *2.xls*, resultou nisto:

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 27329
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryjUAtIb3hLXspUBmo
Host: localhost
Origin: http://localhost
Referer: http://localhost/form
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36 OPR/49.0.2725.47

------WebKitFormBoundaryjUAtIb3hLXspUBmo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="2.xls"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel


------WebKitFormBoundaryjUAtIb3hLXspUBmo--
```

Agora este foi o resultado de um arquivo xls **inválido**, chamado 3.xls, que na verdade é apenas um arquivo de texto conteúdo isto apenas `foo bar`,
 o resultado foi (resumi o resultado para exibir apenas a parte relevante):

```
------WebKitFormBoundarySMenF7hr3QNf4T6l
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="3.xls"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel


------WebKitFormBoundarySMenF7hr3QNf4T6l--
```

Veja, ele acusou que é `application/vnd.ms-excel`, ou seja isso não é o esperado.

---

### Upload de arqivos doc, docx, xls, xlsx, ppt, pptx aparecem como "application/octet-stream"?

Sei que no meu exemplo apareceu `application/vnd.ms-excel`, mas esse é o ponto que quero chegar, não tenho certeza das condições que o upload foi feito, mas uma coisa posso te afirmar, se estiver usando um navegador mais antigo, eu tenho notado que a maior parte dos navegadores modernos, até mesmo o IE11, tenta fazer um bom trabalho para detectar e repassar o mime-type mais correto para um tipo de arquivo especifico, mas realmente não tem como garantir.

Eu até mesmo procurei algum pacote via NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=mime+type, só que só encontrei os que **adivinham** por extensão do arquivo, ou seja não seria uma detecção de mime-type e sim um mapa, o que não seria nada interessante, pois seria instalar algo a mais para algo que você poderia simplesmente validar usando algo como:

```
using System.IO;

...

string Nome = UP_Dados.PostedFile.FileName;

if (Path.GetExtension(Nome).ToLower() == ".xls") {
      //Validou
} else {
      //Não validou
}
```

O máximo que encontrei de algo que poderia **supostamente** funcionar para isto é a função [`FindMimeFromData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107(v=vs.85).aspx), que **não é nativa do C#**, ele faz parte do `urlmon.dll`, o que encontrei de tentativas de uso foram:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62007/1518921
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18554243/1518921

No entanto ao testar 3 arquivos, o `1.xlsx`, `2.xls` e `3.xls` (arquivo falso), obtive este resultado:

> [image: resulatdo do urlmon.dll com FindMimeFromData]

É importante notar que o `urlmon` é uma parte do Internet Explorer que estiver instalado no seu servidor, meu IE é o mais atualizado e mesmo assim esses 3 documentos não foram reconhecidos, logo a solução não é tão funcional quanto se espera (eu tentei as duas respostas linkadas acima)

---

### Como resolver para detectar o mime-type?

**Por enquanto não tem como fazer**, ao menos não encontrei nenhuma solução que use por exemplo uma cópia do arquivo `MAGIC` (https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic), então por enquanto a solução mais próxima seria talvez checar o `ContenType` (mesmo que seja algo que possa ser manipulado) e se aparecer `application/octet-stream` então usaria um **fallback** para checar a extensão, algo como isto:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

...

string ContentType = UP_Dados.PostedFile.ContentType;
string FileName = UP_Dados.PostedFile.FileName;
bool validate = false;

string[] AllowedTypes = {
    "application/excel",
    "application/x-excel",
    "application/ms-excel",
    "application/x-msexcel",
    "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
};

//Para o fallback, acaso o navegador enviar a extensão octet-stream ou zip
string[] FallckExtensions = { ".xls", ".xlsx" };
string[] FallbackMimes = {
    "application/zip",
    "application/octet-stream",
    "application/x-zip-compressed"
};

//Se ContentType for um dos FallbackMimes, então checa a extensão
if (FallbackMimes.Contains(ContentType)) {
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileName).ToLower();
    validate = FallckExtensions.Contains(extension);
} else {
    //Se o ContentType enviado pelo navegador não for octet-stream ou zip testa o AllowedTypes
    validate = AllowedTypes.Contains(ContentType);
}
```

Exemplo no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ln7izz)

> Se não for trabalhar com XLSX então remova do script:

- `".xlsx"` de `AllowedExtensions`
- `"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"` de `AllowedTypes`
- `"application/zip"` e `"application/x-zip-compressed"` de `FallbackMimes`

> **Nota:** Se encontrar alguma solução melhor irei revisar a resposta